# Accessing partition created on Linux from Windows

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning

I have an external HDD. It was shipped with an NTFS partition, but that works problematically under Linux, so I repartitioned it to exFAT. I did it on Linux by removing the existing partitions (there was some special partition for Windows, I removed it too), but not the partition table, then creating a new partition. After that, I formatted the new partition to exFAT. The partition table now looks like the ones usual for pendrives. Linux can work with the drive fine, but Windows cannot see the partition. It recognizes the device, but does not offer any new drives. I tried on both Windows 7 and 10. What is required to make it work under Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so again, if im reading this correctly, then windows cannot read a drive formatted to exFat using another operating system.

from what ive found this is a very common problem among mac users. and one thing you could try would be HFSExplorer (http://www.catacombae.org/hfsexplorer/)

but another solution i just found might be on "askUbuntu"
(https://askubuntu.com/questions/706608/exfat-external-drive-not-recognized-on-windows)
specifically

> "After some trial and errors, I've been able to format an exFAT partition on >Ubuntu that is working on Windows 10. The trick is to add the msftdata flag >on the partition (regardless if partition is aligned or not):
>
> ```
> sudo parted <DEVICE> set <PARTITION_NUMBER> msftdata on
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> sudo parted /dev/sde set 1 msftdata on
> ```
>
> And it worked for me in Windows 10!
>
> And in case it helps someone, this is how I created a single aligned exFAT >partition in the first place:
>
> ```
> sudo parted /dev/sde mklabel gpt
> sudo parted -a optimal /dev/sde mkpart primary '0%' '100%'
> sudo mkfs.exfat /dev/sde1"
> ```

Credits to dbernard (im not sure if im allowed to quote other answers)

Comment: I'm not trying to use a Linux filesystem on Windows. I am trying to use exFAT.

Comment: ok, ill edit it